# Calculating permutations for multiple questions and responses

Tags: permutations

We are administering a survey and trying to determine how many permutations exist for the combination of question numbers and and responses in order to check our work.

Specifically, we have a set of three survey questions, and four possible responses for each question. The respondent of the survey can select all that apply, so for each question, a maximum of four and a minimum of one response can be selected for each question.

E.g.: Who is the decision-maker for activity A?  Self, spouse, other household member. [apply this question for three activities, with the same responses. multiple responses can be selected.]

How many possible combinations of responses could there be across the three questions?

Formulas in excel or R are welcome.  Thanks!!

Comment: One correction: for the responses in the example, the fourth response is "other non-household member."

Answer (score 2):

For each individual questions there are four binary options (checked box or blank box), so each question has $2^4 - 1$ possible answers. The $-1$ is the option where all fields are left blank, which you want to excluse.

Then the total number of possible combinations is $(2^4 - 1)^3$.

Comment: Thank you! So for three question with four possible responses, and with multiple responses, it would be 15x15x15, correct?  Appreciate your help!

Comment: @FBRK_21 yes, I think that's right. You're welcome!